# How to write this in haml?

Tags: haml

What is that i should write to convert this to haml

When I tried like this

```
%p
  We prefer questions that can be 
  %b answered
  . not just discussed.
```

I got Illegal element: classes and ids must have values error.

IS there any way i can get the dot not bolded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
%p
  We prefer questions that can be 
  <b>answered</b>. not just discussed.
```

**Edit**

As @mark pointed out below the reason you were receiving the error was because if a line starts with a . haml is expecting a class name in order to render a div with that class.

```
\.
```

escapes the .

Comment: Using your help i wrote as 
%p We prefer questions that can be <b>answered</b>. not just discussed.
It worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mark's answer is still going to be the best, for readability.

You *could* do this in pure HAML by using the `>` operator on the `b` tag to remove surrounding spaces. However, you'd need to insert a non-breaking space before the bold word to keep it separate.

```
%p
  We prefer questions that can be&#160; 
  %b> answered
  \. not just discussed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the leading period as it's evaluating it as a div with a class.

```
%div.my_class 
== 
.my_class  
== 
<div class='my_class'></div>

%p
  We prefer questions that can be 
  %b answered
  \. not just discussed.
```

Comment: This would put a space between answered and the .

Comment: It added an additional space the output what i saw in UI is We prefer questions that can be **answered** . not just discussed.

Comment: At least you know why you were receiving the error. Maybe Ant could include this then there would be one complete answer. ;)